# Delete all documents from a collection based on a condition and create missing ones

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Now this is something that I already have managed to implement, I am just wondering if there is an easier/better way to do it as I am just starting to work with Mongoose and MongoDB.

Lets say that I have a couple of documents within a collection that have Name fields (I hope I got the terminology right), like this: `[{Name: "Name1"}, {Name: "Name3"}]`, lets call it `NamesConfiguration`.

Now I also have a configuration array `config` with names: `["Name1", "Name2"]`.

My objective is to remove all names from `NamesConfiguration` that do not exist in the `config` array, and then add all names from the `config` array that do not exist in the `NamesConfiguration`, so my final collection should be `[{Name: "Name1"}, {Name: "Name2"}]`.

```
try {
  const config = ["Name1", "Name2"];
  const NamesConfiguration = await UIConfiguration.find(); // getting all available nameconfigs from the db

  NamesConfiguration.forEach(async (nameConfig) => {
    if (!config.includes(nameConfig.Name)) {  // loop through and delete the ones that are not within the array
      console.log("deleting" + nameConfig.Name);
      await UIConfiguration.findOneAndDelete({ Name: nameConfig.Name });
    }
  });

  // loop through the array and see if the names are present
  config.forEach(async (configName) => {
    let found = NamesConfiguration.find((nameConfig) => nameConfig.Name === configName);

    // create new nameconfig if not found
    if (!found) {
      console.log("Creating" + configName);
      let NameConfigToAdd = new UIConfiguration({
        Name: configName
      });
      await NameConfigToAdd.save();
    }
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

I just want to know if there is a better, "more proper" way of doing that operation. In my case even if this can potentially impact performance it will nto be an issue at all, since I will never have more than 10-20 entries.

Solved it by following Yousaf's answer:

```
  const availableConfigs = (await UIConfiguration.find()).map(
    (availableConfig) => {
      return availableConfig.Name;
    }
  );
  const configNamesToAdd = robotsNames
    .filter((robotName) => !availableConfigs.includes(robotName))
    .map((configName) => {
      return {
        Name: configName
      };
    });

  const deleteCondition = {
    Name: { $not: { $in: robotsNames } },
  };

  await UIConfiguration.deleteMany(deleteCondition);
  await UIConfiguration.insertMany(configNamesToAdd);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in following steps:

1. Delete all the documents in the collection whose `Name` field's value is present in the `config` array.

   To delete any document whose `Name` field's value is not in the `config` array, write a delete query using `$in` and `$not` operators.

   ```
   UIConfiguration.deleteMany({ Name: { $not: { $in: ["Name1", "Name2"] } } });
   ```
2. Fetch all the documents whose `Name` field's value exists in the `config` array. You can do this using `$in` operator

   ```
   UIConfiguration.find({ Name: { $in: ["Name1", "Name2"] } });
   ```
3. Iterate over the returned array of documents and filter out those name strings in `config` array that do not match any document's `Name` field value.
4. Finally, insert all the names in the filtered array in the collection using `.insertMany` method

   ```
   UIConfiguration.insertMany([/* filtered name objects */]);
   ```

For further details on methods and operators used above, see:

- [db.collection.deleteMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/#db.collection.deleteMany)
- [db.collection.insertMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/#db.collection.insertMany)
- [$in operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html)
- [$not operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, the deletion works, however I can't figure out the insertion. If I start with Name1 and Name3 in the db, and array is 1 and 2, after deletion in the db should be only Name1 as 3 is not in the cfg array, and that works. Then Name2 should be added to the db since that is present in the cfg array but missing in the db. The deleted documents are irrelevant in this case, so its figuring out which items from the array to add to the db, that are not already there

Comment: Read from step 3. In this step i mentioned how to figure out which names should be added in the collection after the delete operation. Deleted documents are irrelevant but deleted count is not, it is needed to check if there's any name in the `config` array that should be added in the collection.

Comment: Thats my point, I dont see how the deleted count is relevant, what if my documents are Name1  Name3 Name4 Name5 Name6 Name7 and so on until 100 and my config is Name1 Name2 only, then there would be 98 deleted documents, but only one needs to be added

Comment: Ah yes, i see your point. Check the updated answer. You don't need to check deleted document count. After delete operation, just fetch the documents using `$in` operator.

Comment: I updated the my question with my implementation of it and accepted your answer. Also I dont think I need a filter on the .find(), in both cases it will give me all documents.